# Table vertical lines row heights

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, line-spacing

I have to rely on you guys again. I thought it was a simple job, it wasn't.
And again I have to rely on you guys.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\tabcolsep=0.11cm
\small
\caption{caption}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirowcell{2}{looong\\long\\text} & {} & \multicolumn{5}{p{6cm}}{\center long longer longest text  long longer longest text  long longer longest text  long longer longest text  long longer longest text} & {} & \multirowcell{2}{**}\\ \cline{3-8}
& * & \multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}}{long long text} & \multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}}{long long text} & \multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}}{long long text} & \multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}}{long long text} & \multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}}{long long text} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{ long longer longest text long text} & \\ \hline
1   &2  &3  &4  &5  &6  &7  &8  &9\\ \hline
0   &1774&  83.05\% &81.72\%    &85.78\%    &81.14\%    &100\%  &86.34\%    & -4.11\%  < 0.02\%\\ \hline
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \hline
124 &1650   &86.43\%    &81.56\%    &85.77\%    &80.95\%    &100\%  &86.94\%                       & -0.64\% < 0.02\%\\ \hline
144 &1630   &87.02\%    &81.53\%    &85.77\%    &80.91\%    &100\%  &87.05\%    & -0.03\%< 0.02\%\\ \hline
145 &\multirowcell{1}{x1j iv =\\ 1629}  &87.04\%    &81.53\%    &85.77\%    &80.91\%    &100\%  &87.05\%    & -0.01\% < 0.02\%\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Instead of multicolumn{p} I have tried multirowcell, which produced the lines great, but row height was a mess.
And obviously it provides like 20 10000 badness errors.
I think this table exceeds my teX knowledge. Please help!

Comment: Why guys, not dolls? :o)

Comment: I think I was not aware that dolls were into LaTeX, my mistake :D

Comment: For future references \multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}|} does add the right border.

Answer (score 3):

Is this more like you want? I traslated your dimensions into the geometry package keys = …

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[textwidth=160mm,  textheight=235mm, headheight=26pt,  hmargin=25mm, top=25mm]{geometry}
    \geometry{showframe}

%     \usepackage[showframe, margin = 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
    \usepackage{ragged2e}%
     \usepackage{array ,multirow, makecell,, caption, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{cellspace} 
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{X, Y}


    \usepackage{stackengine}
    \setstackEOL{\\}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \def\npc{ \let\% = \relax}
    \tabcolsep = 3pt
      \small
      \caption{caption}
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|>{\bfseries\boldmath}Sc|*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}S{X}<{\,\%}|}>{$}c<{$}|}%
      \hline
    \multirowcell{8}[-1ex]{looong\\long\\text} & \multirowcell{8}[-1ex]{*}%
     & \multicolumn{6}{S{p{9.9cm}}|}{\centering long longer longest text long longer longest text long longer longest text long longer longest%
      text long longer longest text} & \multirowcell{8}[-0.4ex]{\boldsymbol{**}}%
    \\ \cline{3-8}%
    &  & long long text\npc  & long long text\npc  &
     long long text\npc  & long long text \npc &
     long long text \npc  & long longer longest text long text \npc & 
    \\ \hline
        1 &2 & 3 \npc & 4 \npc & 5 \npc & 6 \npc & 7 \npc & 8 \npc & 9\\ \hline
        0 &1774& 83.05 &81.72 &85.78 &81.14 &100 &86.34 & -4.11\%< 0.02\% \\ \hline
         ... \npc & ... \npc  & ...  \npc . & ... \npc  & ...  \npc & ...  \npc  & ...  \npc  & ... \npc  & ... \npc  \\ \hline
        124 &1650 & 86.43 & 81.56 &85.77 &80.95 &100 &86.94 & -0.64\% < 0.02\% \\ \hline
         ... \npc & ... \npc  & ...  \npc . & ... \npc  & ...  \npc & ...  \npc  & ...  \npc  & ... \npc  & ... \npc  \\ \hline
         134 & 1640 & 86.72 & 81.55 & 85.77 & 80.93 & 10 & 87 & -0.35\,\% < 0.02\,\% \\ \hline
         ... \npc & ... \npc  & ...  \npc . & ... \npc  & ...  \npc & ...  \npc  & ...  \npc  & ... \npc  & ... \npc  \\ \hline
        144 &1630 &87.02 &81.53 &85.77 &80.91 &100 &87.05 & -0.03\%< 0.02\%\\ \hline
        145 & \Centerstack{x1j iv = \\ 1629} &87.04 &81.53 &85.77 &80.91 &100 &87.05 & -0.01\,\% < 0.02\,{\%}\\%
         \hline
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but is that code really working? Might be strange, but I am missing some columns in the row below.. Tried to input the missing items myself, but it cameout weird again. Also those long lines left and right of the table, is the table made to be page width and height?

Comment: @Deramite - A statement such as "Tried to input the missing items myself, but it cameout weird again." is quite unclear, and it certainly is not actionable. Please be more specific. Separately, if you don't want lines to outline the text block, don't specify the `showframe` option when loading the `geometry` package.

Comment: @Deramite: Sorry, there was a misoperation on copying the code. It's fixed now. As Mico said, the vertical lines at the margins come from the `showframe` option of geometry, I used it to check everything was OK. Just remove this option.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the edit, it works now. Layout should look like ![this](https://i.gyazo.com/fda04cb267ea247b5c064bf273f0ca52.png).
It also gives 20 10000 badness errors :(

Comment: Do you mean the result of compiling my code yields this result?!!

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I purely copy-pastied it and 20 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 28--28
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 long errors came out. What maddness is this? I am compiling pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX, changing it only reduced badness to 10 (changed it to pdfLaTeX).

Comment: @Bernard, your solution works! And result is very nice (+1). If OP can not reproduce your solution can only means, that he has (i) outdated LaTeX installation or (ii) he made some changes into your code.

Comment: @Deramite: I've updated my answer, with simpler code, now that I understand better what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well after a long time spent on this table, I have found an easy solution. It might look much better using advanced techniques, but I want to leave it as a reference to always go for K.I.S.S(keep it simple & stupid).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx}
\usepackage{array ,multirow, makecell, cellspace, caption, tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\setlength{\textheight}{235mm} \setlength{\textwidth}{160mm}
\setlength{\headwidth}{160mm} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0mm} \setlength{\topmargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{25.10403pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\tabcolsep=0.11cm
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{caption}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|c|}
\hline
{} & {} & \multicolumn{5}{p{8cm}|}{\centering Long Long text} & {} & {} \\ \cline{3-7}
Text & Text & Text & Text & Text & Text & Text & Text & * \\ \hline
1 &2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\ \hline
0   & \textbf{1774}&    83.05\% &81.72\%    &85.78\%    &81.14\%    &100\%  &86.34\%    & $|-4.11\%|  < 0.02\%$\\ \hline
... & \textbf{..}. & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \hline
124 &\textbf{1650}  &86.43\%    &81.56\%    &85.77\%    &80.95\%    &100\%  &86.94\%    & $|-0.64\%| < 0.02\%$\\ \hline
... & \textbf{...} & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \hline
134 &\textbf{1640}& 86.72\% &81.55\%    &85.77\%    &80.93\%    &100\%  &87.00\%    & $|-0.34\%| < 0.02\%$\\ \hline
... & \textbf{...} & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \hline
144 &\textbf{1630}  &87.02\%    &81.53\%    &85.77\%    &80.91\%    &100\%  &87.05\%    & $|-0.03\%|< 0.02\%$\\ \hline
145 & \Centerstack{$\bm{formula}$ = \\ \textbf{1629}}  &87.04\% &81.53\% &85.77\% &80.91\% &100\% &87.05\% & $|-0.01\,\% |< 0.02\,\%$\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item Table notes.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It produces this:
[image: outcome]

However, one must be aware that the \multicolumn width on first row has to be changed in order to incorporate this kind of layout into other page settings (mine are wider). For the default settings 5cm looks good.

Thanks everyone for their answers, I would't have done it without your ideas and suggestions!

Comment: The table presented in this answer may be close (or at least closer...) to what *you* need at the moment. Unfortunately, it's not clear how this "solution" addresses the issues you raised (unfortunately, not all that clearly) in your initial posting. The new material in the right-hand, "mathy" column is, frankly, particularly confusing. How can, say, the absolute value of `-3%` be smaller than `2%`? Please do take the time to explain how the new material solves your typographic needs.

Comment: @Mico Well for one, it has 0 badbox errors, which was the issue before. Secondly, the layout is improved (good enough for me). I thought the point of these answers were to find a solution that works better, not the best one there is? And the contents of the table is clearly another topic, which has not been raised in the question. Are you fishing for mistakes at this point?